# SQL Server: Best practices to save datetime with different timezone in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to save DateTime with TimeZone associated.

I have an order and for each order, tracking timezone is different and wants to convert it to UTC timezone and also to the local timezone.

So original time always different for each order and want to save the DateTime with a different timezone.

What is the preferred way of handling this kind of situation?

Comment: Convert input to UTC, store UTC, convert output to a timezone when appropriate.

Comment: I tend to store as UTC and convert to local in the client-side's presentation layer.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, But tomorrow local timezone can be changed. Is it good idea to save timezone in one of the column i.e "CST", "PST", etc.?

Comment: @amaze Let's say your client is a web browser.  JS will easily convert to local including DLS and changes in Timezones (back and forth).    Again, the U in UTC is universal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving your datetime as UTC, if you want to convert a UTC time to a specific timezone time you can use `AT TIME ZONE` in your select statement/view or function.

example:

```
SELECT GetUtcDate() AT TIME ZONE 'central european standard time'
```

If you want to save the timezone, I would suggest you save it in your "Users" table. This way the user can modify it, and you could use it in your queries or in your client to display the time in the correct timezone.